# Rails and how make a subselect selecting ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm new to Rails and I know this is a simple question but it's driving me crazy.
My app is built with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.
I' writing an app to manage hotel-like rooms reservations.
So this class represents the Accommodation:

```
class Accommodation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and this one is the reservation:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accommodation
end
```

Reservation does have a field named `accommodation_id` where the id of the accommodation is stored

Now I have to check the available Accommodation in a given date range, so I wrote this method:

```
def self.check_availability(params)
    # This return the unavailables accommodations
    ids_to_exclude = Reservation.select(:accommodation_id).where('start_date < ? AND end_date > ?', params[:reservation_end_date], params[:reservation_start_date])

    # HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    accommodations = Accommodation.where("id NOT IN (?)", ids_to_exclude )

    accommodations
  end
```

The first query works but the second one returns:

```
SELECT `accommodations`.* FROM `accommodation` WHERE (id NOT IN (NULL))
```

and I tried to output `ids_to_exclude` and is not NULL

what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I solved this with Arel. I wrote the solution in a comment below

Answer (score 0):

`ids_to_exclude` needs the ids to be extracted

Try

```
 reservations_to_exclude = Reservation.select(:accommodation_id).where('start_date < ? AND end_date > ?', params[:reservation_end_date], params[:reservation_start_date])

 reservations_to_exclude.each do |r|
    ids_to_exclude << r.accommodation_id
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I found the solution with Arel avoiding `each do` blocks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do two database hits for that and you should probably make it a scope while you're there. Also, I'd call passing `params` to a model method bad form, you should be explicit about the arguments to make things easier to understand and maintain:

```
class Accommodation < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.available_between(start_date, end_date)
        joins(:reservations).where('reservations.start_date >= ? and reservations.end_date <= ?', end_date, start_date)
    end
end
```

Then you can say things this:

```
all_available = Accommodation.available_between(params[:reservation_start_date], params[:reservation_end_date]).all
```

or this:

```
some = Accommodation.available_between(params[:reservation_start_date], params[:reservation_end_date])
                    .where(some_other_conditions)
                    .limit(10)
                    .order(:price)
```

Comment: I thought about join at first too, but I discarded the idea due to NULL reservations on joins. I've just tried your method and I got no results because it build an inner join, so Accoomodation with no reservatons wouldn't appear

Comment: @DrDuke: You could `joins('left outer join reservations on ...')` to manually force a LEFT JOIN and add a `reservations.id is null` to the `where` conditions.

Comment: Yes, you are right: I could manually force the join but I was looking for something without manually forcing and without using `to_sql`. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I tried again this query and it returns the accommodation that has reservations (and I'm looking for the opposite). My query with Arel doesn't work neither cause returns the same as yours :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution with Arel:

```
reservations = Reservation.arel_table

available_rooms = Accommodation.where(:id => reservations.project(:accommodation_id)
      .where( reservations[:start_date].lt(params[:reservation_end_date]) )
      .where( reservations[:end_date].gt(params[:reservation_start_date]) ))
```

Comment: This wouldn't work cause I need the Accommodations whose id are not in the subquery. Trying to tweak the query I've an error saying this: `Cannot visit Arel::SelectManager`